# Input ngModel in *ngFor binds to same value for all inputs

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let trxList of trxNumberList; let i= index">
        <td>{{i}}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="trxNumber-{{i}}" class="form-control" minlength="1" maxlength="20" [(ngModel)]="trxList.trxNumber" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is my table body, When I key in first input box, all the other inputs are binding to this value. Image attached. Please help.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Component code:

```
trxNumberObj = new Transaction;

ngOnInit() { 
  for(var i= 0 ; i <= 10; i++ ){ 
    this.trxNumberObj.count = i; 
    this.trxNumberList.push(this.trxNumberObj); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: what does trxList  and trxNumberList have.Not understanding why you are trying [(ngModel)]="trxList.trxNumber"/>. Can you attach the data as well.?

Comment: sure .trxNumberList is a array of Transaction object.. which contains variables like transaction Number, name, comments etc.. trxNumberList : Transaction[] = []; and I need 10 rows so I created 10 objects and pushed it to a array list.                                                                       
 trxNumberObj = new Transaction;                      
  ngOnInit() {
    for(var i= 0 ; i <= 10; i++ ){
      this.trxNumberObj.count = i;
      this.trxNumberList.push(this.trxNumberObj);
    }
  }

Comment: what do you want the ngModel equal to be ?the transaction number ?

Comment: Yes, I want to enter 10 different transaction numbers in those input fields.

Comment: @Raj, always add any additional info in the question instead of comment to make it more readable. This time I added the piece of code to your question. Also remember to add all related code in your original question. This piece of code you presented in comment was very crucial information for solving this problem ;)

Comment: Sure @AJT_82, This was my first post in SO so not sure how it works. Will improve next time Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, no problem at all, I understand well that it is difficult to asses what is needed when you are new. We all have been there! :) Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Picked from your comment, the following piece of code:

```ts
trxNumberObj = new Transaction;

ngOnInit() { 
  for(var i= 0 ; i <= 10; i++ ){ 
    this.trxNumberObj.count = i; 
    this.trxNumberList.push(this.trxNumberObj); 
  } 
}
```

This behavior in template is because objects are mutable in JS. So what you are doing now, is pushing the **same** object to the array, which means that all objects in the array have a reference to the **same** object. What you need to do is to push new objects in the array:

```ts
ngOnInit() { 
  for(var i= 0 ; i <= 10; i++ ){ 
    this.trxNumberList.push({count:i++});  // push new object every time!
  }
}
```

You seem that you have a model for your object, so adapt that accordingly in above code.

Comment: Yes you are right. I realized it before seeing this and got working. This is what I did.                                              
    trxNumberObj : Transaction;                                                    
    ngOnInit() {
    for(var i= 0 ; i <= 10; i++ ){
      this.trxNumberObj = new Transaction;
      this.trxNumberObj.count = i;
      this.trxNumberList.push(this.trxNumberObj);
    }
  }                                                                                                      
 Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 5):

Use the following

```
<input type="text" name="trxNumber-{{i}}" class="form-control" minlength="1" maxlength="20" [(ngModel)]="trxNumberList[index].trxNumber" />
```

This should do the trick.Let me know if it doesnt

Comment: Nope, It dint work. This is my DOM                                                    <input _ngcontent-c10="" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" maxlength="20" minlength="1" type="text" ng-reflect-minlength="1" ng-reflect-maxlength="20" ng-reflect-name="trxNumber-0" ng-reflect-model="33">

Comment: Updated my ans ..check.it ..dont copy paste,i am in phone,so not sure if the variable names are okay

Comment: I tried this way, It's still not working. :( I tried all the possible cases, not sure what is the problem.. I'm not copy pasting..

Comment: okay !just try  <input type="text" name="trxNumber-{{i}}" class="form-control" minlength="1" maxlength="20" [(ngModel)]="trxNumber-{{i}}" /> ..This should work ,try this just to check,dont assume it to be the final solution

Comment: Nope ngModel dosent accept interpolation. Throws error: [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="trxNumber-{{i}}"/>

Comment: ma be create a simple plunker so that i can look at the exact issue !

Comment: Thanks @vikk I got that working. Your suggestions make me think twice. Thanks for your time.. :)

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!